# Stop all Localhost servers/Backround processes

Tags: networking, server, background-process

so my current issue is when I go to the browser type 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' it redirects me to a Facebook page?
if there is any way to stop all servers located on *localhost*
or kill the background task that is redirecting me to the Facebook page it would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

edit 2: heres the sudo iptables --list output:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

and for the cat nsswitch.conf command:

```
passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if `/etc/hosts` has been modified? Do you have an Apache or nginx service running? 

Comment: Please add more information ... does this act the same with different browsers?

Comment: What is the output of  **sudo iptables --list"**

Comment: Can you run this test?  Close every process or program, then open your browser and go to localhost.  In a separate terminal window, issue the following command:  **netstat -antp | grep 127.0.0.1**  and update your question with the output.

Comment: @mondotofu Okay i did it...

Comment: the netstat output looks normal. Port 631 handles printing. What about the iptables command?

Comment: Please post the output of **cat /etc/nsswitch.conf**  This file tells how your name services are resolved.   https://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf

Comment: @mondotofu alright i did both of those things...

Comment: I don't know what to make of the blank entry after netgroup in the /etc/nsswitch.conf... I was expecting **netgroup: nis**   To effect this change you'd have to edit /etc/nsswitch.conf and reboot.  Before doing that, can you give the output of **cat /etc/hosts** to see if there's anything unusual there?

Comment: @mondotofu I did nothing unusual there

Comment: Ok.  when you enter localhost:631  into your browser, do you get CUPS home page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the boot media from which you installed this, such as USB drive?

If so, then try booting from that and see if you have the problem with the web browser misdirecting localhost to a facebook site.  If that's true, then I recommend a full reinstall.